# AS3 / FlashDevelop - Using compiler constant in Embed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I'd like to use a compiler constant to modify the path of some embedded files, which is different for different projects (which share the same source code)

Ie. convert this:

[Embed(source = 'mypath/myfile.png')] public static const myimage:Class;

into something like:

[Embed(source = CONFIG::gfx_path+'myfile.png')] public static const myimage:Class;

where CONFIG::gfx_path is 'mypath/'

Problem is that doesn't compile it (Error: invalid metadata). In fact you cant even do this: "mypath/"+"myfile.png" because it'd give the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a problem accomplishing this?  What was the problem?

Comment: Hi. Problem is that doesn't compile it (Error: invalid metadata). In fact you cant even do this: "mypath/"+"myfile.png" because it'd give the same error.

Comment: Perhaps conditional compilation is not the way to go. Set up different asset-directory and add the one to you source path, you need four your build. This can be nicely accomplished with ANT or Maven or you just use a different configuration file for te different compilations.

Comment: My intuition is that you can't use "code" in metadata.

Comment: @flextras its possible to use compiler constants in metadata so I was hoping for some trick that'd let them be added to strings

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic yep, already looked into –source-path and is the closest to a solution, but I was really hopping to be able to add compiler constant to a string :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use executable code in Embed tags (or any metadata).

The `Embed` meta data tag (along with a myriad of other specific code types)  is executed at compile time. Normal code involving variables/methods is executed at run time. If you don't know the difference, Compile Time code is executed when your build your project and is actually a part of the build. Run time is executed as the application is running.

You cannot execute run time code at compile time and vice-versa. All embeds must be explicitly defined at compile time for them to succeed. It can be a pain, but the application has to know exactly what to embed *before* it compiles. That is the whole point of embedding.

Comment: It is possible to use compiler constants in metadata (I tried, it works) so I was hoping for some trick that'd let them be added to a string. It is not run time code. Just a trick that'd convert 2 constants into 1. And that should be feasible to be done before compiling.

Comment: You could just load in the assets using Loader? That would allows you to combine strings with constants.

Comment: @xLite they have to be embedded in the swf

Comment: Best you can do is simply make 1 constant with the entire string you need as you said it works with a single constant.

Comment: @xLite the constant is a path. There's hundreds of files using that path